# Clip path doesn't work in SVG sprite

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-sprite

Folks,

I am experiencing issue while using SVG sprite that has a symbol with clipped path. Looks like this a known issue but I can't figure out solution by reading existing documentation out there.

I have a SVG sprite file named, icon.svg; content of which is shown below:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="bell" viewBox="0 0 22 22" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
    <path d="M17.3 8.8c0-2.9-2.3-5.3-5.3-5.7v-.2c0-.5-.5-.9-1-.9s-1 .4-1 .9v.2c-3 .4-5.4 2.8-5.3 5.7C4.7 14.7 2 14 2 15.7c0 2.5 2.6 1.9 6.1 1.5v.3c0 1.4 1.3 2.5 2.9 2.5 1.6 0 2.9-1.1 2.9-2.5v-.3c3.5.4 6.1 1 6.1-1.5 0-1.8-2.7-.8-2.7-6.9zm-4.8 8.7c0 .6-.7 1.1-1.5 1.1s-1.5-.5-1.5-1.1c0-.2 0-.3.1-.4h2.6c.2.1.3.3.3.4z"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="lock" viewBox="0 0 20 22" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
    <clipPath id="lock-clip">
      <path d="M16.4 8.2h-1.2V7c0-2.7-2.3-5-5.2-5-2.9 0-5.2 2.2-5.2 5v1.2H3.6c-.6 0-1.1.5-1.1 1V19c0 .6.5 1 1.1 1h12.8c.6 0 1.1-.5 1.1-1V9.2c0-.6-.5-1-1.1-1zM7.5 7c0-1.3 1.1-2.3 2.5-2.3s2.5 1 2.5 2.3v1.2h-5V7zm1 9.6l.8-3c-.4-.2-.7-.6-.7-1.1 0-.7.6-1.3 1.4-1.3s1.4.6 1.4 1.3c0 .5-.3.9-.7 1.1l.8 3h-3z"/>
    </clipPath>
    <path d="M-3.4-3.6h26.7v29.1H-3.4z" clip-path="url(#lock-clip)"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="envelope" viewBox="0 0 30 22" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
    <path d="M3 19h24V4.8l-12 6.7L3 4.8"/>
    <path d="M15 9.7L27.4 3H2.6"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Now I am referring this SVG in my markup as following:

```
<svg role="img" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
   <use xlink:href="/src/assets/svgs/icons/icons.svg#bell" />
</svg>
<svg role="img" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
   <use xlink:href="/src/assets/svgs/icons/icons.svg#lock" />
</svg>
```

First one shows up correctly but second one does not. Upon further finding, I see that there is some sort of issue with clip-paths and SVG sprites.

Is there any workaround for that? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Don't put clipPath elements within symbol elements, move it outside.

Comment: @RobertLongson sorry it took so long for me to reply. Moving it outside did not work. I suspect this is because of the fact that xlink:ref creates shadow DOM for the Symbol you are trying to refer.

Comment: @RobertLongson I could manage to resolve this issue another way. It requires Illustrator. When you create two shapes/path on top of each others, use Path window to subscract/combine both path into one. Then, export that as SVG. This way, you avoid clip-path in exported SVGs.